# View.Select not available in Ember unit test

Tags: ember.js

I have a component `my-component` that includes a `{{view "select"}}` I want to unit test. In the unit test I use `moduleFor('my-component')` and load the component into the DOM. The error that shows is that `Assertion Failed: select must be a subclass of Ember.View` which seems to originate from `handlebarsGetView()`. I stepped through the debugger and noticed that the container doesn't have view:select.

I feel like I'm missing something with the resolver. Why can it not locate the select view? I also tried manually adding `view:select` in the needs callback for the test but then I get a complaint that it cannot add `view:select` because it does not exist.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ember.js tests fail when using select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27502919/ember-js-tests-fail-when-using-select)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use Ember.Select? I recall this one being different for some reason, and I think the core team has plans to overhaul it in the near future.